# Windows 10 IoT UWP setting proper DI

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I am currently working on some application on Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT. What I did for now is to create sample Universal Windows Application which looks like this:

[UWP project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID2i8.jpg)

What I would like to do now is to setup proper DI. I have installed Autofac container and created class Bootstrapper for configuring it. I have found one explanation how to do it here: [link](http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/Getting-Started-using-Autofac-for-Windows-Universal-Dependency-injection/), but I hope it can be done better. What I mean is: I do not want to initialize container in MainPage object, but I want to have MainPage object resolved using container. Maybe anyone has got some working simple example how to achieve this? I do not want to couple MainPage with container, but I am looking for something like registering global container which resolves every object including MainPage.

I think that this can be configured somehow in App.xaml.cs, but I have no idea where and how. Can someone suggest something?

Best Regards,

Comment: Noone has got any idea?